# send arraylist from a controller action to gsp

Tags: grails

I wanted to send an arraylist from controller to gsp. and then retrieve the data from the arraylist through JSON as below:

```
def getMS()
    {
        ArrayList aList=new ArrayList()
        aList.add("a")
        alist.add("b")
        render aList as JSONArray 
    }
```

and in gsp:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: base + "/Login/getMS",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (aList) {
                   //var json_obj = $.parseJSON(aList);
                    alert(aList[0]) ; 
                }
            });
```

but my index value in aList[0] does not retrieve "a" that it should. I have sent arrays in java and C# successfully. but how to do this in grails?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send arraylist as JSON

```
render aList as JSON
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I tried with --- render aList as JSONOUTPUT,render aList as JSONARRAY without any success except render aList as JSON.